# R: Defining large arrays

Tags: arrays, r

I need a large arrays with size greater than int numbers. This is my code:

```
input <- array(0,c(n,i,j))
```

*n* is '33', *i* is '134395553' and *j* is '671'. The value of *i* is greater than the maximum value of integer, so I get this error:

```
Error in array(0,c(n,i,j)) : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed 
In addition: Warning message:
In array(0,c(n,i,j)) :
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
```

So, What can I do for such large array?

---

Unfortunately I need such large array. I have a rating matrix of 163949 items and 671 user. I want to build a priority matrix so I will have an array of 671 users and 134395553 items. Also I am extracting 33 feature for each (user, priority) pair, which means I need an array of 33 by 671 by 134395553.

Comment: That is an insane quantity of data ([148 terabytes](https://www.google.com/search?q=33*671*134395553*48+bytes+in+gigabytes&oq=33*671*134395553*48+bytes+in+gigabytes&aqs=chrome..69i57.18205j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

Comment: Assuming you don't actually have that much information to process -- that most of the elements are 0 / irrelevant / no information. I searched for sparse array packages and found [`slam`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/slam.pdf). I've never used it, so at your own risk. You might also check @jangorecki 's [`data.cube`](https://github.com/jangorecki/data.cube) project.

Comment: There's a good chance you don't really *need* an array of this size. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Use `??"Memory-Limits"` to check on limits to objects

Answer (score 0):

`as.bigz` in the library `gmp` lets you store large sized integer values.

```
i <- as.bigz(134395553)
i
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 134395553
```

Comment: The problem is not about large integers, but massive arrays.

Comment: Agreed. This one is building a large one.